# Flash Builder 4.7 build versioned SWC files of a Library Project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I can't find this anywhere, but I imagine it's quite straightforward to do.

In an ActionScript Library Project in Flash Builder how can I build a versioned release of the library from the files in the src directory?

Comment: What do you mean by a versioned release? Do you want the version number in the file name like this: my_library_v1.0.0.swc?

Comment: A versioned release... like you say, numbers in the file name. In JavaScript I can tag the working copy of a library whenever it's due for release by using SVN.